# Google drive file preview with api access token in iframe

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

How we can get preview of Google drive files in web without login into Google account. In current scenario only public files are visible through embed link, we need to show preview of file in iframe which are not public and without login. We have access token for Google drive api.

Comment: you have asked the same question 4 times in 2 days.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot view private data without logging-in. You need to [login via the OAuth flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#basicsteps). That token can be used to view your files, not of others.

> Before your application can access private data using a Google API, it
>   must obtain an access token that grants access to that API. A single
>   access token can grant varying degrees of access to multiple APIs.

Comment: I have access token but i do not know to how to use it to open file in browser.